# codeigniter url http://www.website.com/index.php/index.php/page

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ive been struggling to get a .htaccess file working on codeigniter, im having that issue when you load any other page aside index that, every time you click on a link in my nav bar it tacks on an index.php/, so after the first click on a link, you end up with things like http://www.website.com/index.php/index.php/page

When I open an image from site 
http://website.com/new/index.php/website.com/new/img/gallery/fw1.jpg

My link same as 
index.php/About">Aboutour team

My config file
$config['base_url'] = 'website.com/new/';

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's in your .htaccess file?

Comment: I dont have any .htaccess file now but it didn't work with

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: how are you writing your your nav links? You should probably be doing something like `site_url('page');` to get the correct URI. Have a look at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

I use the following .htaccess file, which has always worked for me with CodeIgniter:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

You should also check your application/config/config.php file to make sure it has the following lines (a blank base_url setting means CodeIgniter will auto-generate it):

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

You might also want to check you're generating the links themselves correctly. You can use site_url() for every link to ensure maximum portability. e.g.

```
<a href='<?=site_url('about')?>>About</a>
```

Comment: Don't use `base_url()` to generate links to your website's pages. That's what `site_url()` is for.